# ODBC Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

Tags: odbc

(Environment is Linux CentOs7)

I'm fiddling with odbc.ini file and testing the connection each time I make a change:

```
isql -v gdHive
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Within odbc.ini file I've been trying different variations of the description name value pair. This originally was set to:

```
# Description: DSN Description.
Description=Hortonworks Hive ODBC Driver (64-bit) DSN
```

I tried changing this to

```
Description=gdHive
```

This did not change anything wrt the error I pasted above.

Here's the whole config, it's my first time setting this up so I'm not sure what I've missed:

```
# HS2 service discovery with ZooKeeper (ServiceDiscoveryMode=1).
ZKNamespace=/hive/hiveserver2

# Set to 1 if you are connecting to Hive Server 1. Set to 2 if you are connecting to Hive Server 2.
HiveServerType=2

# The authentication mechanism to use for the connection.
#   Set to 0 for No Authentication
#   Set to 1 for Kerberos
#   Set to 2 for User Name
#   Set to 3 for User Name and Password
# Note only No Authentication is supported when connecting to Hive Server 1.
AuthMech=1

# The Thrift transport to use for the connection.
#       Set to 0 for Binary
#       Set to 1 for SASL
#       Set to 2 for HTTP
# Note for Hive Server 1 only Binary can be used.
ThriftTransport=1

# When this option is enabled (1), the driver does not transform the queries emitted by an
# application, so the native query is used.
# When this option is disabled (0), the driver transforms the queries emitted by an application and
# converts them into an equivalent from in HiveQL.
UseNativeQuery=0

# Set the UID with the user name to use to access Hive when using AuthMech 2 to 8.
UID=

# The following is settings used when using Kerberos authentication (AuthMech 1 and 10)

# The fully qualified host name part of the of the Hive Server 2 Kerberos service principal.
# For example if the service principal name of you Hive Server 2 is:
#   hive/myhs2.mydomain.com@EXAMPLE.COM
# Then set KrbHostFQDN to myhs2.mydomain.com
KrbHostFQDN=hive.hadoop.p3.int.example.com

# The service name part of the of the Hive Server 2 Kerberos service principal.
# For example if the service principal name of you Hive Server 2 is:
#   hive/myhs2.mydomain.com@EXAMPLE.COM
# Then set KrbServiceName to hive
KrbServiceName=hive

# The realm part of the of the Hive Server 2 Kerberos service principal.
# For example if the service principal name of you Hive Server 2 is:
#   hive/myhs2.mydomain.com@EXAMPLE.COM
# Then set KrbRealm to EXAMPLE.COM
KrbRealm=HADOOP.PROD.INT.EXAMPLE.COM

# Set to 1 to enable SSL. Set to 0 to disable.
SSL=0

# Set to 1 to enable two-way SSL. Set to 0 to disable. You must enable SSL in order to
# use two-way SSL.
TwoWaySSL=0

# The file containing the client certificate in PEM format. This is required when using two-way SSL.
ClientCert=

# The client private key. This is used for two-way SSL authentication.
ClientPrivateKey=

# The password for the client private key. Password is only required for password protected
# client private key.
ClientPrivateKeyPassword=
```

The error message only says "Data source name not found, and no default driver specified". I'm not sure how to set this data source name or choose default driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "`Description`" keyword's value is entirely cosmetic in an ODBC DSN.  It has no functional use.  You can set it to any arbitrary string.

ODBC will be very hard to learn by trial-and-error shots in the dark.  I suggest you take a look at the [official ODBC specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/introduction-to-odbc?view=sql-server-2017).  You might also look at some docs for the Driver Manager in your environment, such as [this for iODBC](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/FAQ#What%27s%20an%20odbc.ini%20and%20what%20do%20I%20put%20in%20it%3F), or [this for unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/odbcinst.html).